# Use existing ModelSerializer with JSONResponse

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Twitter authentication view that doesn't use a viewset so the auth can be handled on the backend. The view takes in the `oauth_token` & uses Twython to get the profile & create a Twitter model.

Currently I just return status `201` on success, but to alleviate the need for another request after creation, I'd like to return the created model. I have a `TwitterSerializer` already which defines the `fields` that I want to include, so I'd like to be able to reuse this if possible.

**TwitterSerializer**

```
class TwitterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Twitter
        fields = (
            "id",
            "twitter_user_id",
            "screen_name",
            "display_name",
            "profile_image_url",
        )
```

When I try to use this, I get the error that `Instance of TwitterSerializer is not JSON serializable`.

```
            serialized = TwitterSerializer(instance=twitter)
            return JsonResponse({ "created": serialized })
```

I could return a serialized instance of the model using `serializers.serialize()`

```
            serialized = serializers.serialize('json', [twitter, ])
            serialized = serialized[0]
            return JsonResponse({ "created": serialized })
```

I could pass the `fields` kwarg to `serialize()` but I don't want to have to repeat myself if I don't have to. So would it be possible to re-use my `TwitterSerializer` in this case? I'm having trouble finding a direct answer since most docs assume you'll be using a ViewSet when using serializerss understandably, and this feels like an edge case. I'm open to suggestions for refactoring this approach as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After serialization, you can get your data using `data` attribute of serializer like this.

```
serialized = TwitterSerializer(instance=twitter)
return JsonResponse({ "created": serialized.data })
```

You should use Django rest `Response` instead of `JsonResponse` like this

```
from rest_framework response
serialized = TwitterSerializer(instance=twitter)
return response.Response({ "created": serialized.data })
```